# javascript validation: comparing 2 text box values

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I have a table with 5 rows and 2 columns. Each cell contains a text box. I want to show error if one of the text boxes in each column is empty. I want both text boxes in a row shld be filled or both shld empty.

How can i do this via Asp.net validation controls?

I want to extend CompareValidator so that it will validate only if the controlToValidate and controlToCompare both have some text in it or both are empty.

Comment: well, do you want to use javascript validation, or ASP.net validation.. they are not quite the same

Comment: i want to use client side validation using Asp.net validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) and handle its [`ServerValidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx) event (and, optionally, its [`ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx) for client-side validation).  You could do one on the page and check all the rows, or you could have one per row and use the [`ControlToValidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx) property to give you context to the row you're validating.

Any example of the client-side validation is going to depend on your layout and any JavaScript framework that you're using.  It might look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox11" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox12" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox21" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox22" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox31" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox41" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox42" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox51" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox52" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="TextBoxPairValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox11" ClientValidationFunction="TextBoxPairValidator_ClientValidate" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        window.TextBoxPairValidator_ClientValidate = function (sender, args) {
            var other = document.getElementById(sender.id.slice(0, -1) + '2');
            args.IsValid = (sender.value === '' && other.value === '')
                           || (sender.value !== '' && other.value !== '');
        };
    }());
</script>
```

That example obviously assumes a fairly simple layout, and fairly static naming (i.e. if your controls are in a naming container, you may not be able to use the ID trick to go from one text box to the other).  Hopefully that's enough to get you started.